# invalid syntax in SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This does not compile in SQL server 2012:

```
with q as (
select row_number() over (order by ActionName) as rn, *
from [xxx].[dbo].[Action] a
)
```

It says 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Should this compile and if not how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start your statement with `;` try this

```
;with q 
as (
select row_number() over (order by ActionName) as rn, *
from [xxx].[dbo].[Action] a
)
SELECT * FROM q
```

and CTE should be followed by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with q as (
select row_number() over (order by a.ActionName) as rn, a.*
from [xxx].[dbo].[Action] a
)
```

Comment: i think `;` at beginning is not necessary ? i use sql-server no error if no `;`

Comment: not necessary, if it is the first statement of the batch. Apparently that was not the case, as OP says Muhammed Ali's answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
with q as (
select *, row_number() over (order by ActionName) as rn
from [xxx].[dbo].[Action] a
)
```

Comment: select is obvious after this !!